# Why am I unable to rollback an edit?

Tags: support, bug, rollbacks

I'm trying to rollback a particular edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22224158/2024761) but for some reason am unable to rollback the edit. I'm getting the below error message when trying to rollback.

[image: Rollback Problem]

I'm trying to rollback from [Revision 4 to Revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22224158/revisions) because that particular edit actually breaks the code comment. Not sure why am unable to roll it back. Can anybody throw some light on this?

Comment: Someone edited it a few minutes later so couldn't try a proper repro. Worked fine when I rolled back after that. Could it be something like you can't rollback whilst there is a suggestion pending?